# Adapting iOS UI to work for tvOS

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, tvos, apple-tv

We have an iOS app and we were asked to also support tvOS. All our UI is done in .xib files, but the problem is that all the sizes for views, margins, text, etc. are in points. That was totally fine for the iPhones and iPads, as the points are pixels multiplied by a scale to get them to look the same on all resolutions.

But when we built the app for tvOS, all our views are small and in the center of the pages. I read that this is caused because the resolution for tvOS is 1080p, with a scale of 1x. See article [here](http://arctouch.com/2015/11/apple-tv-developers/).

For the UI to look the same, I would like to multiply everything by a scale of 4. By everything, I mean again: view size, text size, margins, spacing, etc.

Is there a way of doing such a thing without completely rewiring the UI?

Comment: Could you add some screenshots to your question?

Comment: I am not allowed to post screenshots of the UI, but I think I made it pretty clear: all the buttons/images/spacings are smaller than they should have been. I will probably end up creating a tvos resource bundle with copies of all the xib files.

Comment: Maybe you could write a little CLI tool that opens .xib files and multiplies the values? If all the values are like half of what it should be, than it shouldn't be hard to do.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that I only have one copy of the xib files and I reference them on both projects(iOS and AppleTV). So I wouldn't be able to have them like this. What I ended up doing, was to create new xib files for tvOS and multiply everything with the scale. Your solution would only make what I did easier, but wouldn't fix the problem in only one file.

Comment: @Scorpio Did you ever solve this? :)

Comment: @HenningHall as I mentioned in the comment above yours, I couldn't find an elegant solution so I duplicated the .xib files for tvOS and changed all the values in the new ones. Luckily for me, there weren't that many files.